# Ubuntu 12.10 Macbook Pro Install Problems

Tags: installation, 12.10, wireless, dual-boot

I have a Macbook Pro (probably the newest one, but NOT the retina one) here. I want to dual-boot Ubuntu 12.10 on it, but I've been have many troubles. YouTube has offered me no help; same with Google.

If I make a DVD or CD (the CD would have to be of Ubuntu 12.04 due to file size), it boots from it, but won't even get to the purple screen. It just stays on the first black screen with a white blinking cursor. Nothing changes.

I can't make a bootable USB stick for mac, though. I do have another computer with Ubuntu on it, but ever since it started to crash when I make a bootable usb, I started downloading more programs, which caused it to just say 'installation failed' immediately. I tried UNetBootin, but that doesn't work with macs. I tried the terminal method, but that makes the USB stick unrecognizable by the computer, making it useless. I think this is my best bet, but it's not working anymore.

Once I do get Ubuntu booted up, installed, ready to go, the wireless capabilities are completely disabled. I checked under NetworkManager, but it just says Wired Connections, Enable Networking, Edit connections. No wireless thingy at all. I tried installing b43 but I don't know how to activate it. I eventually just delete it and try again. It happens every time. Reinstalling Ubuntu didn't help either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Follow instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

You need to install the cutter application, use that to unpack the proper firmware.  Then you use modprobe -r to remove all the drivers... then modprobe to load the driver you want.  I've used the STA, B43, & wl.

The link I posed is very descriptive, read it carefully and follow the steps based on your outputs... good luck.